# Replace this ' character when queried to my PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace

Here is my PHP Code

It cannot be save to my database I wonder why..

```
 txt = str_replace("♣","'", $string);
```

Comment: because you try to assign the returned value of a function to a string.

Comment: the error is it does not query anything in my database. Maybe ' character is treated inside the database as something

Comment: Please, write your insert query.

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_contents( functionname,editorcontent) VALUES('". $name ."','". $str ."')";
    $res = mysql_query($query,$con); //DO QUERY

Comment: You know the *mysql* extension is unmaintained and deprecated, right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all write your insert query then we can tell what is the issue

Also you are assigning return value to a variable while variable name doesn't start with `$`

Change

```
txt = str_replace("♣","'", $string);
```

to

```
$txt = str_replace("♣","'", $string);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use function `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$txt = str_replace("♣","'", $string);

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_contents( functionname,editorcontent) VALUES('". $name ."','". mysql_real_escape_string($str) ."')"; 
$res = mysql_query($query,$con); //DO QUERY
```

For more detail read https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string